# Using token with ouath-server2 and laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

What / how should I do with this token to gain access to my system? ( I am using the postman to give me the token, but do not know what to do with it. )

Answer (score 0):

If you are using http://oauth2.thephpleague.com/ I asume you follow the documentation in order to set up the OAuth 2.0 Server.

This is the chart that explain how this process works
[Oauth Diagram from oauth2.phpleague](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UTKmA.gif)

In general, you should have some routes protected **by a middleware** (this middleware requires you to provide a valid token to consume it).

example: if you have a resource that is called CART and  is protected by the middleware, you will need to provide the token in order to access this resource.

in order to provide the right token, you need to ask it to the server.

> "I am using the postman to give me the token, but do not know what to do
>   with it.

I would give you a real-world example:

if you need to open a door, the first thing you need to open it is the key  right?. So with postman you just asked for that key.

**After you have the key** (token) you will be able to open **"the door"** that is key protected.(the resource you want the client to consume)

Hope this help.
best regards.

Comment: i'm using this https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel
like you said, i have "the key" but how can I open the door ? What should I do ? I have the routes in my application, I have the users in my DB.

Comment: Could you please post your routes file?